# Protractor - Cucumber : Continue scenario verification steps in case if verification is failed instead of skipping

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, ui-automation, assert

I am right now using protractor cucumber framework and as of now if I have 3 verification statement in Then and in case if statement 2 fails then the remaining steps are skipped. I don't want to skip remaining steps,

I tried using Chai-as-promised with

```
expect(condition).to.eventually.equal(something).and.notify(next);
```

... but I'm getting below error in this case :

> Error: Invalid Chai property: notify.next. See docs for proper usage of "notify". at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (ProtractorLatest/node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/proxify.js:47:17) at World. (ProtractorLatest/executionScripts/stepDefinitions/dropdown.js:33:110) at Generator.next () at fulfilled (ProtractorLatest/executionScripts/stepDefinitions/dropdown.js:5:58) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

I have added my sample code below. Can anyone help me on resolving this code.

```
Then(/^I should see all operators in dropdown$/, async function() {

    const dropdownActual = new Array("+", "/", "%", "@", "-");
    for (let i = 0; i < (await homePage.dropdown).length; i++) {
      await expect(homePage.dropdown.get(i).getText()).to.eventually.equal(dropdownActual[i]).and.notify(next);
      await homePage.dropdown.get(i).click();
      console.log("Dropdown : " + dropdownActual[i]);
    }

    const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
    this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");

    await homePage.dropdownclick.click();

});
```